# Download the file with Selenium python in a desired folder or current tests directory folder

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

I am trying to download a file using selenium python. I have the basic setup method which is:

```
class BaseTestCase(object):


    def setUp(self): 
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://qa.smartsimpleqa.com")



    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

Now when I run my tests using this setup method my test saves the file in the download directory instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject\"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

Also be aware that if you set wrong path as `"download.default_directory"` value, you will get no exceptions- `chromedriver` will just use `Downloads` folder as default